# updating solutions in eclipse marketplace client

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-marketplace

if I have an eclipse plugin/feature, which is released so that it has one p2 repository per each plugin version, that is present in eclipse marketplace, then will eclipse detect new versions of the plugin when I run check for updates? Or do I actually *have to* put all versions of the plugin in the same p2 repository, except those that are not compatible with some eclipse releases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put all versions of your plug-in into the **same update site** (p2 repository):

If a plug-in is installed via Eclipse Marketplace Client, the update site is added to *Window > Preferences: Install/Update > Available Software Sites*. Automatic update or *Help > Check for Updates* will search for updates in all available and enabled software/update sites.

Several p2 repositories can be combined to a [composite repository](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Composite_Repositories_(new)).

Comment: seems I may have no easy way to create a single update site, because it would require some ant scripts, tycho does not support such scenarios (actually why?). it would deploy the p2 repo to maven repositories. my repository manager does support p2 repositories, but only in the pro version that I obviously do not have.

Comment: You can use a composite repository to combine multiple p2 repositories (see my edited answer).

Comment: I know, but this is this thing that seems difficult due to no direct support of it in tycho. Tycho cannot make eclipse composite repositories and I would need ant scripts just for that purpose, and a way to upload it to, for example, artifactory generic repository. seems quite a lot of work